# HTML5 <Video> reset video after slide

Tags: javascript, php, html, html5-video, carousel

I use the carousel slider from Bootstrap. But when I put images and videos in it but when I loop the videos they won't stop looping. But I want them to stop and reset so when it gets back to that slide the video starts from the beginning, not somewhere in the middle of the video. Also I was wondering if it's possible to not set an interval but play the video till the end before going to the next slide.

**JS**

```
$("#myCarousel").carousel({
    interval: 4500
});
```

**PHP**

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <video id="myVideo" loop autoplay muted><source src=""></video>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <video id="myVideo" loop autoplay muted><source src=""></video>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a JSFiddle. I have removed `loop autoplay` from the video tags.

```js
$("#myCarousel").carousel({
  interval: 4500
});

$("#myCarousel").on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
   var vids = $(this).find(".active video");
   if(vids.length > 0){
      vids[0].pause();
      vids[0].currentTime = 0;
      vids[0].play();
   }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <video id="myVideo" muted><source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"></video>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <video id="myVideo2" muted><source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"></video>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```